# Critical CSS cache embedded scripts and mis behaves with Gulp/ npm

Tags: javascript, css, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

**A quick little breakdown:**
I'm setting up a boilerplate. At the moment I have Gulp converting scss to css via **gulp-sass** and then after I use [critical](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical) to get the above the fold CSS & embed it in the head via .
Initially it worked the problem came after using [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) in conjunction. It started wrapping noscript tags inconveniently round both the embedded CSS & loadCSS script & noscript.

After reverting from my use of loadCSS on the src index.html file, when I "gulp" it still outputs the cached loadCSS scripts & the  (which loadCSS requires).

The funny thing is my src has a normal link tag with the href to the css file. but it is outputting to the target file everything the way I wanted it the critical css, loadCSS script and noscript encasing the link. It's weird.

I think its a cache issue with gulp or critical. I've cleared the npm cache but had no luck.I don't believe it is a bug.
**Question:**
I need to know what is causing this cache problem and how to fix it.

**My critical gulp task:**

```
gulp.task('makeCriticalCSS',['sassToCss'], function () {
critical.generateInline({
    base: 'dist/public/',
    src: 'index2.html',
    css: ['./dist/public/css/app.css'],
    width: 320,
    height: 480,
    htmlTarget: 'index.html',
  //  styleTarget: 'css/critical.css',
  //  extract: true,
    minify: true
});});
```

Comment: Try to return the stream (ie: `return critical.generateInline({ .....`)

Comment: @DaveLunny  I added return but it's still it's writing index.html with the old script+noscript code I've removed from index2.html., it's in memory somewhere I'm just not sure where.